# A Query on IELTS score for express entry Canada, as a secondary applicant

Tags: canada, ielts

Can any one help us with regarding IELTS score?

I am VFX artist with 7 years of experience.

This is my IELTS Score and am the secondary applicant. My wife already got the required band score.

- Speaking: 5.0
- Listening: 5.0
- Writing: 5.0
- Reading: 3.5
- Overall score: 4.5

Clarify me whether I am eligible to apply for the express entry visa as a secondary applicant?

Comment: I don't think there are minimum scores required for the secondary applicant, you just won't get any points that can be applied to the primary applicant's total.

Answer (score 1):

A score of 5 in any module of IELTS means that the person could mostly understand the question, but can answer in very vague terms, like circling around, but not to the point. i.e. if the question is about Rose, person is talking just about a garden in his answer.

9 bands means using english like a native speaker, 8 means handling complex language almost every time. 7 means most of the time, 6.5 means half of the times, 6 some times, 5 very few times and 5 means handling structural complex english very occasionally. 4.5 & 4 questions the user's ability to understand question.

Overall score of 4.5 is very low IMHO, but we can not answer without knowing the complete details of your case and the rules of your selected visa category.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the mandatory IELTS band score for secondary applicant?

Comment: IELTS Group (British Council or IDP) itself does not state any pass/fail/minimum-required scores. Its up to individual authorities (i.e. College you are applying or Employer or Embassy, etc.) to decide the minimum required bands. I suggest you to check the rules & regulations of the visa category you are applying.